# check if NSTextfield is empty or not OSX swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I am using a code to set value when user is not inputing a value to a NSTextfield, it does not continue after else if there is value in textfield

Here is an exampel.

```
 func calculateAmountPanels(){

    let fpanelsHigh = Float(panelsHigh)
    let fpanelsWidth = Float(panelsWidth)

    if panelsHighTextField != nil && panelsWideTextField != nil {
        resHightLabel.stringValue = "N/A"
        resWidthLabel.stringValue = "N/A"
        lblScreenHight.stringValue = "N/A"
        lblScreenWidth.stringValue = "N/A"
        lblScreenArea.stringValue = "N/A"
        lblAmountPanels.stringValue = "N/A"
    }
    else {


    ammountPanels = (fpanelsWidth! * fpanelsHigh!)

    printText()

}
}
```

Some advice would be appreciated since OSX coding seem to be different from ios.

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: I want to check if the textfield is empty, and if so return "N/A" in the difrent labels.

Answer (score 1):

I would add this extension:

```
extension NSTextField {
    func setStringValueIfEmpty(newValue: String) {
        if self.stringValue == nil || self.stringValue.isEmpty {
            self.stringValue = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it on the fields, like so:

```
resHightLabel.setStringValueIfEmpty("N/A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the NSTextField's stringValue, e.g.:

```
panelsHighTextField.stringValue != nil
```

As HAS mentioned, you should also test for `panelsHighTextField.stringValue.characters.count` higher than 0.

Comment: You most certainly want to also test for an empty string.